# i2c Installation Failing On Raspberry Pi Running Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, raspberrypi, i2c

I am using a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu, and I've been trying to set up a four-pin OLED screen (without success). For context, [here's the tutorial](https://www.the-diy-life.com/connect-and-program-an-oled-stats-display-for-your-raspberry-pi/) I've been following. I understand that it is intended for Raspbian, but I'm confident that it could work on Ubuntu.

I successfully installed raspi-config on my Pi and used it to enable i2c; however, using the command `sudo i2cdetect` returns `sudo: i2cdetect: command not found`. This is the first problem I came across.

The next step in the tutorial was installing Python, i2c-tools, and Adafruit BBIO. I will list each individual command with the error it returned.

`sudo apt-get install python-smbus` tells me that the package is "not available, but referred to by another package".

`sudo apt-get install i2c-tools` returns a lengthy error message: `Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute/universe arm64 libi2c0 arm64 4.2-1build1 404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute/universe arm64 i2c-tools arm64 4.2-1build1 404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/i/i2c-tools/libi2c0_4.2-1build1_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/i/i2c-tools/i2c-tools_4.2-1build1_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`. I am unsure as to what to do here. Manual installation from the websites referred to didn't work the first time, but I could give it another go. Interestingly, trying to update my Ubuntu version gives me a nearly identical error message. Not sure why...?

`sudo pip3 install Adafruit_BBIO` simply tells me that the command `pip3` does not exist.

Any way I can solve these problems?

Comment: Your problem is `hirsute`, which reached EOL last month. Migrate to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: @karel All the answers on this post seem to be saying how to adapt an older version of Ubuntu, not update it- is this correct? Either way, the methods I tried gave me more 404s. I found a separate tutorial on how to update to 21.10, from which I could update further, but Software Manager says to "check my internet connection". I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and all of this is really confusing.